# ¿Por qué no me deja introducir el nombre de la operación a través del Scanner?

Tags: java, string, scanner

Luego de introducir num_A y num_B, me salta directamente "Escriba la operación que quiere realizar: suma, resta, multiplicación o división"  "Error, el parámetro es inexistente", sin darme lugar a escribir el nombre de la operación. No entiendo porque es que no funciona, imagino que viene por el lado de la String, dado que si uso una variable del tipo int en operación me deja.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Clase11{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int num_A = 0, num_B = 0, resultado = 0;
        int parametro = 0;
        String operacion = ""; 

        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Escriba un numero");
        num_A = teclado.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Escriba otro numero");
        num_B = teclado.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Escriba la operacion que quiere realizar: suma, resta, multiplicacion o division");
        operacion = teclado.nextLine();

        if(operacion == "suma"){
            parametro = 1;
        } else if(operacion == "resta"){
            parametro = 2;
        } else if(operacion == "multiplicacion"){
            parametro = 3;
        } else if(operacion == "division"){
            parametro = 4;
        } else {
            parametro = 5;
        }


        // armo mi Switch case
        switch(parametro){
            case 1: resultado = num_A + num_B;
                System.out.println("El resultado de la suma es " + resultado);
                break;
            case 2: resultado = num_A - num_B;
                System.out.println("El resultado de la resta es " + resultado);
                break;
            case 3: resultado = num_A * num_B;
                System.out.println("El resultado de la multiplicacion es " + resultado);
                break;
            case 4: resultado = num_A / num_B;
                System.out.println("El resultado de la division es " + resultado);
                break;
            default: System.out.println("Error, el parametro es inexistente");
                break;
        }





    }
}
```

Mi consola arroja estos resultados:
`Escriba un numero`
1
`Escriba otro numero`
2
`Escriba la operación que quiere realizar: suma, resta, multiplicacion o division`
 **Entre estas dos líneas aparece mi problema. Quiero que me deje introducir el nombre de la operación**
`Error, el parametro es inexistente`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te dejo el código funcionando.

te comento algunos de los errores en tu codigo.

1.- Scanner.nextInt () no consume el delimitador (por ejemplo, la nueva línea).Eso significa que la próxima vez que llame a nextLine (), obtendrá un String vacío de readInt () anterior. por este motivo no podías escribir la operación.

2.- Para comparar String no se utiliza el == , por este motivo aunque escribieras suma no lo tomaba como un valor valido. en este caso usa equals o equalsIgnoreCase. ademas siempre comparar primero la constante luego la variable para que no de un nullPointer.

por ultimo para no tener problemas use nextLine(), en todos los casos luego de eso lo pase a int, cabe señalar que si escriben una letra el sistema se caerá, para esto tiene que agregar mas validaciones que no vienen al caso.

saludos.

```
public static <T> void main(String[] args)  {
        try {

            String numPantalla_A = "0", numPantalla_B = "0";
            int num_A = 0, num_B = 0, resultado = 0;
            int parametro = 0;
            String operacion = ""; 

            Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Escriba un numero");
            numPantalla_A = teclado.nextLine();
            num_A = Integer.parseInt(numPantalla_A);
            System.out.println("Escriba otro numero");
            numPantalla_B = teclado.nextLine();
            num_B = Integer.parseInt(numPantalla_B);
            System.out.println("Escriba la operacion que quiere realizar: suma, resta, multiplicacion o division");
            operacion = teclado.nextLine();



            if("suma".equals(operacion)){
                parametro = 1;
            } else if("resta".equals(operacion)){
                parametro = 2;
            } else if("multiplicacion".equals(operacion)){
                parametro = 3;
            } else if("division".equals(operacion)){
                parametro = 4;
            } else {
                parametro = 5;
            }
            System.out.println("parametro : "+parametro);

            // armo mi Switch case
            switch(parametro){
            case 1: resultado = num_A + num_B;
            System.out.println("El resultado de la suma es " + resultado);
            break;
            case 2: resultado = num_A - num_B;
            System.out.println("El resultado de la resta es " + resultado);
            break;
            case 3: resultado = num_A * num_B;
            System.out.println("El resultado de la multiplicacion es " + resultado);
            break;
            case 4: resultado = num_A / num_B;
            System.out.println("El resultado de la division es " + resultado);
            break;
            default: System.out.println("Error, el parametro es inexistente");
            break;
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Las cadenas se comparan con el metodo equals:

```
if(operacion.equals("suma")
 {

 }
```

pero tu operacion podria ejecutarse sin el if

```
switch(operacion){
        case "suma":
```